# squeryl partial update doesn't work when trying to update ZonedDateTime

Tags: mysql, scala, jdbc, zoneddatetime, squeryl

For reference I have updated the example given on https://www.squeryl.org/

The partial update doesn't work with Date and gives error "cannot resolve symbol :="

```
update(songs)(s => 
where(s.title === "Watermelon Man") 
set(s.updatedAT := DateUtils.nowUTC)
)
```

Is there a way we can achieve the same